# Trying to make PHP mssql but make returns fatal error

Tags: php, sql-server, makefile, configure

```
make
/bin/sh /Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/include -I/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/main -I/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/php_mssql.c -o php_mssql.lo 
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/include -I/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/main -I/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/php_mssql.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/php_mssql.o
In file included from /Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/php_mssql.c:33:
/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/php_mssql.h:68: error: redefinition of typedef ‘LPBYTE’
/Applications/MAMP/Library/include/sqlfront.h:35: error: previous declaration of ‘LPBYTE’ was here
/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/php_mssql.c: In function ‘php_mssql_do_connect’:
/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/php_mssql.c:760: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/php_mssql.c: In function ‘php_mssql_get_column_content_without_type’:
/Users/myusername/Downloads/php-5.3.5/ext/mssql/php_mssql.c:1113: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘spprintf’ from incompatible pointer type
make: *** [php_mssql.lo] Error 1
```

I'm on step 3 of http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/mssql+mamp+php+mac+osx.
I followed exactly except that I downloaded http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.3.5.tar.gz for this.

Can you help?

Comment: It seems that `/Applications/MAMP/Library/include/sqlfront.h` is causing an error. What does that lib? I never read that.

Comment: Me either. I have no idea what it does. Seems to be a part of the package though.

Comment: It seems to be something about iPhone/iPad/Android programming. Try to remove that path from any environment variables while building that module. Or simple rename that directory while building that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with: https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/issues/96